# Generate C# docs output from in-code XML documentation without Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, documentation

Without building the project is it possible to just scan the code and get the triple slash in-code document and output them? (XML, Markdown, etc.)

```
/// <summary>
/// Resume playing of a previously paused audio with fade in length
/// specified by an argument.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="fadeLengthSeconds">Fade out length to use.</param>
public void ResumeFade(float fadeLengthSeconds)
{
```

Currently I am using Visual Studio **Code** and it seems to know about all my documentation in the Intellisense. I have `.sln` file which seems to link to the assembly containing all the information. If VSCode can read it, I guess there might be other program that is not the full Visual Studio that can generate a doc output from it. (Be it XML or Markdown)

I would like to automatically generate an input for [Slate](https://github.com/lord/slate)

Comment: I would use the .proj file which is text instead of the sln file.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I use Visual Studio Community just for getting the XML then use :

https://github.com/Pxtl/XmlCommentMarkDownGenerator

It is a NuGet package, but works as a CLI tool. Works on macOS with `mono` so you could execute an `exe` file in macOS.

`mono PxtlCa.XmlCommentMarkDownGenerator.exe -i ../../Temp/bin/Debug/Assembly-CSharp.xml -o docs.md`

Comment: There is also markdown CLI for .net: https://github.com/aloneguid/dotnet-markdown-cli-tool